# MySQL joins, left join

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

So am trying to write a MySQL query with a simple join to pull things from two different tables.

The fist table is a students table (Sorry its not prettier I couldn't find a better way to put them in)

```
id  first_name  last_name   major    phone_number
-------------------------------------------------
1   Eric        Larsen      CS       1234567891
2   Sam         Coons       English  1234567891
3   David       Brown       MAE      1234567891
4   Richard     Brown       CS       1234567891
5   Kendra      Griffiths   FCHD     1234567891
```

The second is a scores table, rich now it just has one row,

```
id  student_id  item_id  score
------------------------------
1   1           1        20
```

There is a third table with a list of items but is not really needed for this particular query.

I want to pull all of the students along with there score for scores.item_id = 1 if they have a score, if they don't I still want it to pull the information for the student, well, there name at least.

So here is the query I wrote.

```
SELECT students.first_name, students.last_name, scores.score
FROM students
     LEFT JOIN scores
     ON students.id = scores.student_id
WHERE scores.item_id =1
```

In my mind this should work, it should pull all the students even if there is no score for them because it is a left join but it is only pulling the one student with a score Eric Larsen, The results looks like

```
Eric, Larsen, 20
```

But shouldn't it be:

```
first_name  last_name  score
----------------------------
Eric        Larsen     20
Sam         Coons      NULL
David       Brown      NULL
Richard     Brown      NULL
Kendra      Griffiths  NULL
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will reveal your problem.

```
SELECT students.first_name, students.last_name, scores.score, scores.item_id
    FROM students
    LEFT JOIN scores
        ON students.id = scores.student_id
```

You see `scores.item_id` is `NULL` for all those other rows, so that fails your `WHERE scores.item_id = 1` clause, hence those rows not appearing in your results.

This should get the results you are after

```
SELECT students.first_name, students.last_name, scores.score
    FROM students
    LEFT JOIN scores
        ON (students.id = scores.student_id)
    WHERE (scores.item_id = 1 OR scores.item_id IS NULL)
```

or

```
SELECT students.first_name, students.last_name, scores.score
    FROM students
    LEFT JOIN scores
        ON (students.id = scores.student_id AND scores.item_id = 1)
```

Comment: This got it exept instead of = NULL its IS NULL. Thank you thank you thank you!!!

Comment: Ok fixed my answer with that

Comment: It looks like you edited the post as I was adding the comment but this one works as well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the joined column to your select - columns

Answer (score 0):

The where clause you have put on your SQL query is limiting the result set to one row.  Try removing the where clause.

```
SELECT students.first_name, students.last_name, scores.score
    FROM students
    LEFT JOIN scores
        ON students.id = scores.student_id;
```

Comment: The problem with that is there could be a number of different items that I want to get the scores for. For example there could be two items, in this case they would be assignments for a class. Say homework 1 and homework 2, I want to get all of the students first and last names and if a score is recorded for that particular assignment, that score as well, if there is no score I still want their name

Comment: Thats a valid use case, but how is doing a left join going to help you with that?  The where clause limits the result set to the item as intended, what your asking for would pull back all scores regardless of item_id.  Wanting to pull back all entries in scores and limit them by item_id kind of conflicts.

Comment: So should the query be more like:

SELECT student.first_name, student.last_name, scores.score
FROM scores
RIGHT JOIN students
ON scores.student_id = scores.student_id
WHERE scores.item_id = 1?

Comment: I don't think anything you do to the query is going to get the desired result you would like.  I think it is more about defining what you expect to receive from the query.  You cannot retrieve all joined values in scores and still filter by item_id.  These two interests conflict and are not technically possible.

Answer (score 0):

You have provided a where condition to filter out the records remove that where condition you should get you desired results then.